# Configure EasyBox (Vodafone) with DynDNS

Tags: router, dynamic-dns, dynamic-ip

How can I configure an EasyBox A601 WLAN (from Arcor resp. Vodafone) to send the IP always to DynDNS?

I entered the following:

```
Dynamic DNS       [X]
Diensteanbieter      (DynDNS.org)
Domänenname          mysupersecrethost.dyndns.org (as specified in "My Host" section
Konto / E-mail       myaccountname
Passwort            mysupersecretpassword
```

The update does not work anymore, so that my IP is not correct.
The firmware is the newest available:

```
Firmware Version:  10.02.006 (01.12.2008-11:11:59)
```

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some discussions at [DynDNS community forums](http://dyndnscommunity.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1731&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&start=0) about an update problem since March.

> since 26. March 2009 the update of the IP on DynDNS.org won't work. The log of the router contains the following error message "30.03.2009 21:40:54 DynDNS-Fehler: Der DynDNS-Anbieter meldet Fehler Unerwarteter Server-Fehler. (D002)" (example from 30. March). This means "DynDNS-error: The DynDNS-provider reports error unexpected Server-error. (D002)".

You might want to match your problem with that and maybe check for followups.